# Algolia Magento autocomplete integration

Tags: magento, algolia

I have Algolia configured & returning results from searches but the autocomplete suggestions are not coming up, no algolia div is displayed when typing in the search box - just the normal Magento drop down when conducting a search.

A few things I have checked in the Algolia search config in Magento:

- Enable Auto-completiton menu is set to Yes
- Enable instant search results page is set to Yes

I noticed wording in the Magento Algolia Search config settings near 'Enable Auto-completiton Menu' - 'It requires your theme to expose a top.search template.' I followed the instructions at https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento but am not sure how to troubleshoot the issue.

I am using the EM Themes everything store template demo at http://demo.emthemes.com/everything/index.php/?___store=smartphone_eng

Thanks for any help you can offer

Comment: Did your clear all caches ? do you see any algolia script imported in the page ?

Comment: Yes caches have been cleared & disabled - I can see 3 algolia scripts imported in the page. The bundle.min.js & 2 css files